# VOIP worked with Mint 19.1 & kernel 4.4, fails w/ kernel 4.8

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, ethernet, forwarding, voip

With Linux Mint 19.1, kernel 4.15, I connect to the Internet using WiFi, and want to share the Ethernet connection with a [Grandstream IP Phone](http://www.grandstream.com/products/ip-voice-telephony).

I have done:

> click | network connection | wired connection 1 | edit | ipv4 setting 
>   | automatic dhcp | change to | shared to other computer | click | save

With kernel 4.4, the connection is OK, but, since changing to kernel 4.8, the phone can make calls, but I don't hear the person on the other side. I don't receive calls, either.

I would to know if there is some port to open or something to do with the iptables.

Phone Model: Grandstream GXP1625.

Comment: I would investigate NAT-T issues. Voip works better without NAT and if you are doing a NAT on top of another NAT...

Comment: Please click [edit] and add to the original question: 1) Which model of Grandstream IP phone are you using? 2) What's the configuration for that phone?

Comment: Thank you for the editing. Sorry for my bad english, I'm brazilian and I'm learning yet.

Comment: You mention kernels 4.4 and 4.8 in the title and the question, but also 4.15 in the question. Of the three, which one(s) allow your VoIP to work, and one(s) do not?

Comment: The VoIP works with 4.4. With 4.8 or above the VoIP make calls, the person hears me but I don't hear anything. I don't receive calls, either.

Comment: This has 4 close votes for being a crosspost, but I can't see any comment on what the other crosspost would be. All I can find is [this question on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1126980/551198), which was closed since it was off-topic there (not about Ubuntu). After that one was closed, this was posted here, where it appears to be on-topic. What am I missing?

Comment: I did not understand. Is the post in the wrong topic?